# React Native: Animation opacity transition only runs from componentDidMount

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm trying to run a fade out animation on react native but it will only run once on componentDidMount.

Any other efforts to run the animation, doesn't show the animation even though the function runs.

This class runs on a parent component which renders this component 6 times.

I'm running this react native app with mobx, so typical react lifecycle hooks don't necessarily work as expected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

class FadeOut extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0.3)
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('testing lifecyles compdidmount');
        this.animateDetail();
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        console.log('componentWillUpdate');
        this.animateDetail();
    }

    animateDetail = () => {
        console.log('running animate Detail');
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
            toValue: 0.01, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
            duration: 500 // Make it take a while
            // useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(console.log);
    };
    render() {
        const { fadeAnim } = this.state;
        return (
            <Animated.View
                style={{
                    ...this.props.style,
                    opacity: fadeAnim
                }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}

export default FadeOut;
```

Answer (score 2):

It`s because you don`t revert animated value.

In the constructor you set initial value (0.3) of the animated parameter. Then you animate it down to 0.01.
After it all attempts to animate it to 0.01 will not have visual effects - it is already 0.01.

So, for getting your purposes done you need to animate back the value with `Animated` interface (dynamically or immediately via `setValue(nextValue)` and after that call `animateDetails()` again.

Comment: thank you. It was confusing me because on the .start() callback, if I called this.state.fadeAnim it would show the original value. My solution, set the value at the beginning of the function:    `animateDetail = () => {
        this.fadeAnim.setValue(0.3);
        Animated.timing(this.fadeAnim, {
            toValue: 0.01, // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
            duration: 500, // Make it take a while
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
    }`